# Docker compose containers cannot access internet unless on host network - ipv6 only server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipv6

I am using docker compose on a IPv6 only Debian 11 server. I am having trouble getting internet access from the containers. Communication between the containers works like a charm. However connecting to the ourside world does not. I can only ping to the outside world when I connect to the 'host' network (which I don't want to do for security reasons):

```
docker run -it --rm --network=host registry.ipv6.docker.com/library/alpine ping6 -c 2 google.com
```

^This resolved the address and pings alright. With the default or the bridge network I get `ping6: bad address 'google.com'`

My main question: What is the problem / how do I troubleshoot this?

I tried (in various combinations):

- Compose files network_mode options
- Providing explicit DNS in /etc/docker/daemon.json
- Providing explicit DNS in the container definition for the compose file
- Enabled ipv6 + provide fixed-cidr-v6 in /etc/docker/daemon.json
- Checking the /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd00::/80",
  "dns": ["2a01:7c8:7000:195::8:195:8", "2a01:7c8:7000:195::135:195:135"]
}
```

Note: I did not install a firewall at first. During troubleshooting I installed uwf, which I did not configure and is currently disabled.

Hopefully this output will be helpful:

**With --network=host**

```
> docker run -it --rm --network=host registry.ipv6.docker.com/library/alpine cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1       my-network
::1             my-network

> docker run -it --rm --network=host registry.ipv6.docker.com/library/alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 2a01:7c8:7000:195::8:195:8
nameserver 2a01:7c8:7000:195::135:195:135

> docker run -it --rm --network=host registry.ipv6.docker.com/library/alpine ping6 -c 2 google.com
PING google.com (2a00:1450:400e:810::200e): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:400e:810::200e: seq=0 ttl=118 time=3.365 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:400e:810::200e: seq=1 ttl=118 time=2.848 ms
```

**Without any network**

```
> docker run -it --rm registry.ipv6.docker.com/library/alpine cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      e484aa610139
fd00::242:ac11:2        e484aa610139

> docker run -it --rm registry.ipv6.docker.com/library/alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 2a01:7c8:7000:195::8:195:8
nameserver 2a01:7c8:7000:195::135:195:135

> docker run -it --rm registry.ipv6.docker.com/library/alpine ping6 -c 2 google.com
ping6: bad address 'google.com'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot access the public Internet using ULA addressing. Also, using `fd00::/80` is misusing ULA. The 40 bits following `fd` must be randomly chosen, giving you a `/48` prefix from which you get 65,536 standard `/64` networks (you should only use `/64` networks, other than `/127` point-to-point networks, else you break some IPv6 features). Also, `fe00::0 ip6-localnet` is incorrect as the link-local addressing is `fe80::/10` (notice the `8`) but the next 54 bits must be `0`, essentially making it `fe80::/64`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Ron. I'm new to IPv6 and docker doesn't handle IPv6 smoothly out of the box. I am unsure on what the cidr setting should be. I have tried `fd00::/80`, and now `fdxx:yyyy:zzzz::/64` or the `2a01:xxxx:yyyy:zzzz::/64` IPv6 range of the server. None work. If I manually create an IPv6 network `docker network create --ipv6 testnet` I receive 'Error response from daemon: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv6 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network'. The `fe00::0 ip6-localnet` entry is auto-generated by docker. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You either need to manually forward IPv6 traffic on your host to the specified docker network, or add:

```
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd00:ffff::/80",
  "ip6tables": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```

to your daemon.json which does this for you (like with IPv4).

Here is an Article going into more [detail](https://blog.iphoting.com/blog/2021/02/10/ipv6-docker-docker-compose-and-shorewall6-ip6tables/) and explaining more alternatives (like the ipv6-nat docker image).

Be sure your cidr-v6 is part of the private Address range (fc00:: to fdff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff), otherwise it could be publicly exposed and accessed without a NAT thus becoming insecure.

This is still experimental, and overall IPv6 on docker, especially docker-compose is not great